# Is anyone using Redis in front of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, redis, nosql

I was wondering if anyone is using Redis in front of MongoDB for a more robust permanent persistence layer.

I realize Redis has VM and is adding new features all the time... but want the flexibility of MongoDB for scaling horizontally.

example: I want to use redis for session/pub/sub with nodejs and websocket to the browser, but also store the data in a scalable way in a searchable archive maintained on MongoDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I use Redis often as an index of indexes in front of MongoDB. For example, I generate a key that I use to lookup a set in Redis, then use the members of that set for Mongo queries using $in.